# Bamboo git checkout works too long

Tags: git, bamboo

I have some trouble with git checkout tools in Bamboo. It works too long. For example I have two repos. I can clone them to local machine in 5-10 minutes. But checkout task stucks at

> Fetching 'refs/heads/release-1.69' from
>   'ssh://git@ [path/to/first/repo] .git'.
>
> Git: remote: Counting objects
>
> Git: remote: Compressing objects (120)
>
> Git: Receiving objects (269)
>
> Git: Resolving deltas (83)
>
> Git: Updating references (1)
>
> Git: Total 269 (delta 83), reused 128 (delta 31)
>
> Checking out revision 7c11b20b2495be8bb8091839794c4e80bdc7651e.
>
> Creating local git repository in 'path'

Sometimes this task take 150 minutes, sometimes it even has no end.

Another trouble that stopping plan with that task not stopping the agent. The only way to reanimate agent is restart it.

Is it something wrong with agent? Or I make mistake with configuring repos?
I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378747/massive-git-checkout-times). The only advise is to re-install Bamboo.

Comment: Have you contacted Atlassian to see if it's a known issue, or if they can provide any support?

Comment: Good Idea! I cant find something about it at their documentation or bug tracker.But I asked the same question at answers atllasian a few minutes ago

Comment: If Bamboo is running on a server, can you try a git checkout on the server machine (outside Bamboo) to determine if the problem is with Bamboo or the machine itself?

Comment: It works fine. Git checkout on server machine works correct.

Comment: I decided to use git checkout in script task. It works OK. But intgration with JIRA didn`t work without babmoo checkout task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since a script works well, you could:

- use the script as a first step
- then use the [Bamboo Checkout task](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Checking+out+code) on the same directory: unless "Force CLean Build" is checked, it should see the repo is already checked-out.

That would mean that:

- the Bamboo checkout step would be considerably quicker (nothing to checkout),
- the integration with Jira wouldn't be compromised.

Comment: This is good idea, but it is not solution for original trouble

Comment: @hatesms the original trouble is best addressed by Atlassian support.

Comment: do you have an example how the script has to be defined?

Comment: @Jehof I do not, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that helps, but we had the same problem with TeamCity. Periodically it was hanging on getting an update from a git repository when we used its own VCS connector. We have resolved it by writing script and calling it on first step.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem, the answer provided by Atlassian support was to install 'git' on our bamboo server, and have Bamboo use the git client (by defining an executable). Apparently the java based internal git client built into Bamboo has issues.

Comment: I do the same by executing git trought script task. But is doesn`t fill issues for build. So I decided to do like VonC advise - checkout by script and then by checkout task